# Why is bottom margin inside element box for button but not p element?

Tags: css

Why is it that adding a bottom margin for a `p` element adds space beyond the element's box (that is not affected by the background color set in CSS), but the inverse is true (the margin remains colored) when adding a bottom margin for a button? (I fixed this by using padding only and setting margin to 0 for the p element, so I'm only asking out of curiosity.)

This CSS:

```
.about p {
  padding: 0 4em 2em 4em;
  margin: 0 0 2em 0;
  text-align: left;
}

button {
  margin-top: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}
```

Resulted in (note the white space above the "PORTFOLIO" section but not below the button at the bottom):

[image: margins]

To view the rest of my code, view [CodePen](https://codepen.io/nataliecardot/pen/wjwvLQ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't seem to find any suitable question to close this as a duplicate of, so here's an answer.

You are the victim of margin collapsing in the case of the p.
See this example. The outer element has a yellow background, and you would expect to see this behind the p (above and below), but it "inherits" the p's margin, so what you're seeing is the white background of the body.

```css
.outer {
  background: yellow;
}

.inner {
  background: lime;
  margin: 2em 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <p class="inner">two block elements</p>
</div>
```

The button in your example, however, is not a block element. It has `display:inline-block` by default, so no margin collapsing takes place and the outer div's background is visible around it.

```css
.outer {
  background: yellow;
}

.inner {
  background: lime;
  margin: 2em 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <button class="inner">inline-block in a block</button>
</div>
```

For more information, see [Mastering margin collapsing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing) on MDN.